# Retaining cell formatting in a formula

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, spreadsheet, text-formatting

I'm looking for a way to pass along text formatting when combining cells in a formula.  The image attached shows a similar instance of the result I would like.

If I combine `A1` and `A2` and `A3` with the formula `=A1&A2&A3`,  I would like to return the result of Bark**Tree***Cat* (with Tree bolded and Cat italicized).

[spreadsheet sample](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B6AS_2K-wjAhRGtINmpkWVJnN1E/edit?usp=sharing)

Any thoughts?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This has been asked a number of other times here before and this may be closed as a duplicate.

The only formatting options exposed by Excel functions apply a format mask (eg see [TEXT](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/text-HP005209313.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HP005204211)). To have formatting like **Bold** copied you need to use VBA.